# When click on custom tab open external app in new tab

Tags: salesforcedx, connected-apps, tab, sforce.connection

I want to create custom tab , on click of custom tab . it will open new tab in browser with external application url

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a [WebTab](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_web_tabs.htm&type=5) instead

[image]

See this [post](https://guidemeprod.blob.core.windows.net/guideme-pdf/how-to-create-web-tab-to-open-external-web-application-in-salesforce-5919a5f5f0e6a.pdf) for steps to create a web tab

Comment: I don't want to open external application in salesforce . I want to open external application in new tab and while opening external tab . I want to pass session and user details.

Comment: In that case, I suggest adding Lightning Components in your Custom Tabs and add logic in your lightning component to open it in a new tab https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=aura_add_cmp_lex.htm&type=5

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/248787/open-lightning-component-in-new-browser-tab